# Story where the female lead is born back into her hated family and her mage brother threatened to drop her out of her window with magic

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read a manhwa or comic story about a female protagonist who is brought back into her family, where she is the hated or ignored child.

The third chapter is her backstory on her brother. Her brother mistreats her and scares her with a dead magic animal when he puts it in her room. He then busts into her room and threatens to drop her out of a window with magic unless she apologizes for ignoring him.

I don't remember the name of the story, but the female lead had light brown hair and her brother probably had red hair, I think.

Comment: Is this a manga? A manhwa? Western webcomic? Online novel?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I thought this was "Can we become a family?" but it doesn't have the dead animal or window scene as of chapter 6.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Just Leave Me Be](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/8d52zhi/just-leave-me-be)***, AKA *Please Throw Me Away*...?

> Adele was a hapless orphan until a duke gave her a choice: live as a substitute for his dead daughter, or die on the streets. Despite playing this role to the best of her ability, an order for her assassination was given shortly after he married her off. Miraculously, she is sent back in time and decides to make up for the years wasted living a lie. As ancient ruins call to her, can she use her past knowledge and unexpected help from the Black Knight to defeat the dangers ahead and change fate?

A young girl named Adele believes she's been adopted by a duke to play the role of his dead daughter, Karina Bifta, due to her close physical resemblance to Karina (both have green hair and golden eyes, like the duke himself). She later learns that she too was a daughter of the duke, albeit, an illegitimate one.

In subsequent years, she's bullied by her oranged-haired brother, Kuarn, ignored by the servants, treated with contempt by her stepmother, and ultimately assassinated by a group of knights sent by her father, as she'd outlived her usefulness in his eyes. She then wakes up in bed three years earlier, and resolves not to allow herself to be used by her father, as she was before.

In chapter 31, she comes home and finds a bloody sack in her bedroom, apparently left there by Kuarn to freak her out. In the next chapter, he bursts into her room, and when she fails to speak to him as respectfully as he'd like, he uses his magical powers to suspend her in midair outside of her bedroom window, in order to force an apology out of her.

[image] [image]